# PHP curl with 1ms timeout - enough time for the target's ignore_user_abort(true) to activate?

Tags: php, curl, asynchronous, timeout

I'm attempting to kick off an "async" php job of a long-running script, via a curl request that times out almost immediately. I'm aware better solutions on different stacks exist, but this seems to be a common suggestion when vanilla php is all that's available.

```
$c = curl_init();
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);  // Follow the redirects (needed for mod_rewrite)
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);         // Don't retrieve headers
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);          // Don't retrieve the body
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);  // Return from curl_exec rather than echoing

// Timeout super fast once connected, so it goes into async.
curl_setopt( $c, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS, 1 );
return curl_exec( $c );
```

In the target `$url` I've defined a script that is supposed to ignore a user abort, then do it's own thing.

```
ob_start();
ignore_user_abort(true);

set_time_limit(0);

echo "OK";

ob_flush();
flush();

// wait 5s to help debug
sleep(5);
// processing stuff
```

so with `CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS` set to `1ms`, the script never runs. With it set to `100ms`, it still never runs. With it set to `500ms`, it runs with the expected behavior (the parent script gives up and returns after ~500ms, the expected logic of my script executes after `5s`.

Am I doing something wrong, or is the simple answer that even `ignore_user_abort()` at the top of the script needs a certain amount of time to execute?